# Expand collapse li

Tags: html

I have the following sample list. I want to make it collapsible. Please suggest.

```
<div class="section">

<h2> Accounts:<br />E-interest Certificates</h2>
<ul>                                                                                       <li>Housing Loan</li>

                        <li>Education Loan</li>

                        <li>Deposit Accounts</li>

</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the below link. I think it's works for you.

```
jsfiddle.net/VNkM2/2/
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using bootstrap accordions, there are a few examples on [this website](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp).